# Waiting for the loading of an element in javascript

Tags: javascript, polymer

This might be a stupid question, but I am asking anyways, I have a question about waiting for callbacks.

I am using Polymer in my web development project. In one of my pages, I have a loop that loads an element inside a loop:

```
loop
   "element-a"
end loop
```

I am fetching data from the database and content of "element-a" is populated from the database query results.
I only want to load another "element-a" once "element-a" has finished loading.

Right now, I have a forced delay by using :
    sleepStupidly(usec);
    function sleepStupidly(usec)
    {
    var endtime= new Date().getTime() + usec;
    while (new Date().getTime() < endtime);
    }

But I need a better way of doing this, any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: instead of “sleepStupidly”, you could simply use window.setTimeout. But that will not fix your basic problem, which is that your data is fetched asynchronously, so you won't know exactly when it will be available. Please post the code that fetches the data.

Comment: I don't use polymer, but this sounds like a job for javascript promises - or ajax success.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises#promisifying_xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 0):

As [sheriffderek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479984/waiting-for-the-loading-of-an-element-in-javascript#comment-74016069) pointed out in the comments, promises or jQuery's $.ajax().success() method are probably the best tools to get this done. In addition, good ol' recursion could be used as well. Below is an example of how to use these within a Polymer (v1) component for your case.

```
<dom-module id="example-component">
    <template></template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is:"example-component",
            properties: {
                //...
            },
            fetchIndex: 0,
            idsToFetch: [1, 2, 3, 4],
            elementData: [],
            ready: function () {
                this.loadElement(this.idsToFetch[this.fetchIndex]);
            },
            loadElement: function(idToFetch) {
                var self = this;        // Create a reference for the ".done()" method to use when it fires
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://example.com/getdata",
                    data: {"idToFetch": idToFetch}
                }).done(function (data) {           // This will fire after the response is received, which is where you call the next
                    self.elementData.push(data);    // Save the response data
                    self.fetchIndex++;                                      // Move to the next element
                    if (self.fetchIndex < self.idsToFetch.length) {         // If there's more to fetch
                        self.loadElement(self.idsToFetch[self.fetchIndex]); // Recursively call the same method
                    }
                }).always(function(data){                                   // Optional
                    console.log("Fetch complete for ID: " + idToFetch);
                }).error(function (error){                                  // Optional
                    console.log(error)
                });
            }
        })
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

In summary, call the `loadElement()` method on Polymer's `ready()` handler and provide it the first element to initiate the fetch. Within `loadElement()`, make the fetch to get the data for the element ID passed in. Once the fetch is `.done()` (preferred over but, similar to `.success()`), recursively call the `loadElement()` method again and provide it the next element in the list. This will continue recursively until the `fetchIndex` value equals the length of the `idsToFetch` array.